# AJAX PHP JSON Array data handling

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am producing a `JSON Array` from `PHP` via `AJAX` Request but at the time i am testing to see the data, i cannot seem to output the data at the `AJAX` returned level.

When testing with `AJAX` set to `html` the alerts show but without anything in them.

When testing with `AJAX` set to `JSON` the alerts do not show at all.

When testing the `PHP/JSON` independently the array is populated with the data and seems to be functioning perfectly.

**Q.** `What am i missing to alert the array values?`

**The AJAX**

```
var url = "http://www.xxxxxxx.com/home/secure/bin/colour_manage/btn_preset_css_script.php";

$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url, 
            dataType: 'json',

            beforeSend: function() {

            },
            success: function(data) {

                var myObject = JSON.parse(data);

                // loop over each item
                for (var i in myObject) {
                    if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                       //console.log(myObject[i]);
                       alert(console.log(myObject[i])); 

                    }
                }   
            }
});
```

**The PHP/JSON**

```
$sql = 'SELECT *
     FROM btn_color_presets
    ';

$result = mysqli_query($sql);

$array = array(); // 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) // 
{
     $array[] = $row;
     $index++;
}

header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Don't call `JSON.parse`. jQuery does that automatically when you specify `dataType: 'json'`.

Comment: Are you using firebug?

Comment: ok, now thats got me to [object Object] in the alerts. Nearly there! Thanks!